# to ensure Trump and Bolton are stopped

Tags: gerunds

*The only way to win this war is to ensure Trump and Bolton **are stopped** before they start it*.

https://www.huffpost.com/entry/opinion-parsi-war-with-iran_n_5abd46fde4b055e50acc2e82

I would like to ask whether it is possible to replace the bolded part with "being stopped" or "to be stopped" which I would opt there.

Comment: Why do you think those suggestions are better than "**are stopped**"?

Comment: Where the gerund could be used: "... is by ensuring..."

Comment: I do not think that my alternatives are better. I would choose them on the basis of my – probably limited – knowledge of English. Maybe I would write "should be stopped".

Comment: @bart-leby  No, it's a fine question to ask if "being stopped" can be used.  The short answer is "yes -- with some slight rearrangement."

Comment: The sentence is written in the present simple PASSIVE voice. Why would you put it in the present progressive passive (being stopped)? It would need to be rewritten.

Comment: I have just realized what I do not understand. Why the future is not used? So I have the fourth version: "will be stopped". We are talking about things that should happen in the future. Or nor?

Comment: Although not wrong (with rephrasing), there is no need to change the verbal phrase. Also note that, semantically, the sentence is a little strange. If they are stopped before the war is started—then the war will never happen in the first place, and there will *be* no war to win or lose. (It sounds a little bit like something out of a science fiction novel, where history is changed by going back in time.)

Comment: @Jason Bassford  I think this is a matter of rhetoric, the author is saying that the only way to with the  war s/he writes of  is to stop it before it starts. If it once starts it will be a loss for all sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form:

> The only way to X is to ensure that Y and Z are stopped.

(To X is an infinitive verb phrase that serves as the subject of the sentence.)

is perfectly proper and quite natural. One cannot substitute "being stopped" or "to be stopped" without significantly recasting the sentence.

One could write:

> - To X we must ensure that Y and Z are stopped.
> - To X we must ensure that Y and Z will be stopped.
> - To X, Y and Z need to be stopped.
> - To X, Y and Z must be stopped.
> - Unless Y and Z are being stopped, we are not Xing.

As you can see, each of these changes the form. That last one also changes the meaning somewhat, but it is the closest I could get using  "being stopped".

None of these are a significant improvement on the original, in my view. However, each is grammatical and reasonably natural.